# C++ how to use a copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor

So im trying to create a copy of `myCat` in my main like so

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Cat
{
private:
   string name;
   string breed;
   int age;
   static constexpr double licenseFee = 10;

public:
   void setCatData(string, string, int);
   void showCat();
   void displayAddress(Cat mycat);

   Cat(){
   }
   
   Cat(const Cat &aCat) { //copy constructor
      name = aCat.name;
      breed = aCat.breed;
      age = aCat.age;
   }
 
};


void Cat::setCatData(string catName, string catBreed, int catAge)
{
   name = catName;
   breed = catBreed;
   age = catAge;
}

void Cat::showCat()
{
  cout << "Cat: " << name << " is a " << breed << endl;
  cout << "The cat's age is " << age << endl;
  cout << "License fee: $" << licenseFee << endl;
}

void Cat::displayAddress(Cat myCat) {

cout << "The address of the object is: "<< &myCat;

}

int main()
{
     Cat myCat;
     Cat myCat2 = myCat; //coppy constructor called

     cout << "ORIGNAL CAT" << endl;
     myCat.setCatData("Tigger", "Fluffy unit", 3);
     myCat.showCat(); 
     cout << endl;
     //myCat.displayAddress(myCat);
     cout << "COPY CAT" << endl;
     myCat2.showCat();
   
}
```

However nothing is copied and my output is as such

```
ORIGNAL CAT
Cat: Tigger is a Fluffy unit
The cat's age is 3
License fee: $10

COPY CAT
Cat:  is a
The cat's age is 1
License fee: $10
```

Im not sure why myCat2 doesnt contain the same data is myCat?

Comment: Concerning `Cat(const Cat &Cat)`: It's not a good idea to give the type _and_ the variable the exact same identifier.

Comment: @Scheff ive taken this advice and updated my code :)

Comment: Are you aware that your first copy `myCat` and then assign the values to it? Hence, `myCat2` shows `myCat` in its initial state. (Was that really your intention?)

Comment: @Scheff ahhh i always overlook such simple mistakes. Thankyou all is in order now :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy the object after you've modified it if you want the copy to have the same properties as the original:

```
Cat myCat;
cout << "ORIGNAL CAT" << endl;
myCat.setCatData("Tigger", "Fluffy unit", 3);
myCat.showCat();
cout << endl;
Cat myCat2 = myCat;
cout << "COPY CAT" << endl;
myCat2.showCat();
```

Comment: Omg such a simple mistake yet i overlooked it!! thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor does work, only the copy happens before you set the data.
`myCat2` does not contain the same data since it is a copy of `myCat` with the 'default-constructed' data.

If you want `myCat2` to change when adapting `myCat`, then `myCat2` should be a reference, not a copy.

(Your example with changed constructor signature: https://godbolt.org/z/zE9MjK)